# How to get multiple color rectangle using HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw 6X6 squares with different colors. But the new color overriding the old one. And i want to add eventhandler for every square.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="3000" height="1500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

JavaScript:

```
var xPoint = 30;
var yPoint = 30;

var c  = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

for(var i =1; i<=6;i++)
{
  var tyPoint = yPoint * i;
  for(var j=1;j<=6;j++)
  {
    var txPoint = xPoint * j;  
    var colorcode = CalculateHEX();


    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = colorcode ;      
    ctx.rect(20, 20, txPoint , tyPoint );
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

}

function CalculateHEX()
{
alert('HEX');
var rgbCode ="#";
for(var c = 0;c< 3;c++)
  {
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
    rgbCode  = rgbCode + Number(y).toString(16);
  }
  return rgbCode;

}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9c5P/411/).

Comment: Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/j9c5P/411/

Answer (score 2):

You confused the order of parameters in the [`rect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D.rect) method. It should be:

```
ctx.rect(txPoint, tyPoint, 20, 20);
```

The first two arguments are x and y coordinates of the upper-left corner of the rectangle, and the rest are rectangle width and height.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/j9c5P/413/

Answer (score 0):

Delete following line in your JS:

```
   ctx.beginPath();
```

Now it shows the correct grid because you stopped overwriting.

https://jsfiddle.net/j9c5P/414/